# Why record = cur.fetchone()[0] is all of a sudden a Nonetype

Tags: python, database, sqlite, discord, discord.py

So I am working on a currency system in discord. I used the following code to give money to someone.

```
@client.command()
async def give_money(ctx, member: discord.Member, amount: int):
  connection = sqlite3.connect("testdatabase.db")
  cur = connection.cursor()
  cur.execute(f"UPDATE currency_value_table SET currency = currency - {amount} WHERE   
member_id = {ctx.author.id}")
  record = cur.fetchone()[0]
  if record < amount:
    return await ctx.send("Bruh you too poor to do that!")
  else:
    await ctx.send(f"{amount} given to {member.display_name}")
  cursor.execute(f"UPDATE currency_value_table SET currency = currency + {amount} WHERE member_id = {member.id}")
  connection.commit()
  connection.close()
  database_record = cur.fetchone()[0]
  money = database_record
  await ctx.send(f"You are clearly a broke college student.. you have {money} dollars")
```

However when I run it, I get this message:

```
File "discord.bot.py", line 398, in give_money
record = cur.fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I am unsure of to how this is a Nonetype because if I run this:

```
@client.command()
async def bal(ctx):
  connection = sqlite3.connect("testdatabase.db")
  cur = connection.cursor()
  cur.execute(f"SELECT currency FROM currency_value_table WHERE member_id = {ctx.author.id}")
  record = cur.fetchone()[0]
  connection.commit()
  connection.close()
  await ctx.send(f"You are clearly a broke college student.. you have {record} dollars")
  cur.execute(f"SELECT currency FROM currency_value_table WHERE member_id = {ctx.author.id}")
```

it works fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you executed an `UPDATE` statement rather than a `SELECT` statement, which does not return any data. It's better in this case to execute a `SELECT` statement first to check what the current currency amount is, before updating the table.

```py
cur.execute(f"SELECT currency FROM currency_value_table WHERE member_id = {ctx.author.id}")
record = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove connection.close(), it is not required and check it once!

[image]